# How to return outputstream of .xlsx file

Tags: java, excel

in a java-class i just created workbook like this
 `XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(fis);`
and filled cells with its corresponding celltype. 
now i need to write it as a xxx.xlsx file same time return a BuyteArrayOutputStream.
to do so,

`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);`
`workbook.write(fos);`

`ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`
`workbook.write(outputStream);`
`return outputStream;`

here writing xxx.xlsx fils done successfully but same time it returns outputStream as null?
How do achieve it both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i write it into the outputstream and get byte[]. after that through  IOUtils.write() from   [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/") writing as a file later.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(outputStream);
byte[] b = outputStream.toByteArray();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
IOUtils.write(b, fos);
return outputStream;
```